# Background color transfer

Tags: jquery, html, css

this is *really* simple but I am sleep deprived (newborn baby) and can't seem to get this right.

It's easy, all I want is when a div is clicked, use jQuery to get the bg-color of that div (var currentColor) and set it on another div (no relation, not a child parent or sibling.)

Here's my jquery code:

```
$("#bacon div").click( function(){
    var currentColor = $(this).css("background-color");
    $("#chosenColor").css("backgroundColor" , "currentColor");

});
```

And the fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/dYhMp/

What am I doing wrong? Have I taken the wrong approach or is my brain just too fried to understand what's (not) going on here? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to remove the quotes around the second `"currentColor"`:

```
$("#bacon div").click( function(){
    var currentColor = $(this).css("background-color");
    $("#chosenColor").css("backgroundColor" , currentColor);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dYhMp/3/

Answer (score 2):

You put the variable name between quotes. Remove them:

```
 $("#chosenColor").css("backgroundColor" , currentColor);
```

Answer (score 1):

`currentColor` is a *variable* containing a color string.  `"currentColor"` is a *string* itself.

```
$("#bacon div").click( function(){
    var currentColor = $(this).css("background-color");
    $("#chosenColor").css("backgroundColor" , currentColor);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have "currentColor" as a string, fix it to:

```
$("#chosenColor").css("backgroundColor" , currentColor);
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the double quotes on currentColor when setting the css, as it is a variable. I checked it and it works:

```
$("#bacon div").click( function(){
    var currentColor = $(this).css("background-color");
    $("#chosenColor").css("backgroundColor" , currentColor);

});
```